# VBA for Excel code to find and change formatting of substrings of text within a cell

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using VBA for Excel.
I have code that does the following:

- Take an array of words (called `Search_Terms`)
- I then have a function (see below) that receives the `Search_Terms` and a reference to a Cell in Excel.
- The function then searches the text within the cell.
- It finds all substrings that match the words in `Search_Terms` within the cell and changes their formatting.
- The function shown below **already works**.
- However, **it is quite slow** when I want to search several thousand cells with an array of 20 or 30 words.
- I'm wondering if there is **a more efficient/idiomatic way to do this** (I'm not really familiar w/ VBA and I'm just hacking my way through).

Thank you!

```
Dim Search_Terms As Variant
Dim starting_numbers() As Integer ' this is an "array?" that holds the starting position of each matching substring
Dim length_numbers() As Integer 'This is an "array" that holds the length of each matching substring

Search_Terms = Array("word1", "word2", "word3") 

Call change_all_matches(Search_Terms, c) ' "c" is a reference to a Cell in a Worksheet

Function change_all_matches(terms As Variant, ByRef c As Variant)
    ReDim starting_numbers(1 To 1) As Integer ' reset the array
    ReDim length_numbers(1 To 1) As Integer ' reset the array

    response = c.Value 

    ' This For-Loop Searches through the Text in the Cell and finds the starting position & length of each matching substring
    For Each term In terms ' Iterate through each term
        Start = 1
        Do
            pos = InStr(Start, response, term, vbTextCompare) 'See if we have a match
            If pos > 0 Then
                Start = pos + 1 ' keep looking for more substrings
                starting_numbers(UBound(starting_numbers)) = pos
                ReDim Preserve starting_numbers(1 To UBound(starting_numbers) + 1) As Integer  ' Add each matching "starting position" to our array called "starting_numbers"
                length_numbers(UBound(length_numbers)) = Len(term)
                ReDim Preserve length_numbers(1 To UBound(length_numbers) + 1) As Integer
            End If
        Loop While pos > 0  ' Keep searching until we find no substring matches
    Next


    c.Select 'Select the cell
    ' This For-Loop iterates through the starting position of each substring and modifies the formatting of all matches
    For i = 1 To UBound(starting_numbers)
        If starting_numbers(i) > 0 Then
                With ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=starting_numbers(i), Length:=length_numbers(i)).Font
                    .FontStyle = "Bold"
                    .Color = -4165632
                    .Size = 13
                End With
            End If
     Next i
     Erase starting_numbers
    Erase length_numbers
End Function
```

Comment: Some of your code is missing.  But, with a routine that must write to the worksheet, you can improve speed somewhat by turning off ScreenUpdating and setting the calculation mode to manual.  Also, disable Events. You may get some improvement by using the Long data type instead of the Integer, since VBA converts Integers to Long anyway.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld You're correct. Some of the code is missing (apologies if that caused confusion). Absolutely fascinating. I didn't know that these things existed (ScreenUpdating, calculation mode, etc.). Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code bellow might be a bit faster (I haven't measured it)

What it does:

- Turns off Excel features, as suggested by @Ron (ScreenUpdating, EnableEvents, Calculation)
- Sets the used range and captures the last used column
- Iterates through each column and applies an AutoFilter for each of the words
- If there is more than one visible row (the first one being the header)

  - Iterates through all visible cells in currently auto-filtered column
  - Checks that the cell doesn't contain error & is not empty (this order, distinct checks)
  - When it finds the current filter word makes the changes
  - Moves to the next cell, then next filter word until all search words are done
  - Moves to the next column, repeats above process
- Clears all filters, and turns Excel features back on

---

```
Option Explicit

Const ALL_WORDS = "word1,word2,word3"

Public Sub ShowMatches()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, ur As Range, lc As Long, wrdArr As Variant, t As Double

    t = Timer
    Set ws = Sheet1
    Set ur = ws.UsedRange
    lc = ur.Columns.Count
    wrdArr = Split(ALL_WORDS, ",")
    enableXL False

    Dim c As Long, w As Long, cVal As String, sz As Long, wb As String
    Dim pos As Long, vr As Range, cel As Range, wrd As String

    For c = 1 To lc
        For w = 0 To UBound(wrdArr)
            If ws.AutoFilterMode Then ur.AutoFilter     'clear filters
            wrd = "*" & wrdArr(w) & "*"
            ur.AutoFilter Field:=c, Criteria1:=wrd, Operator:=xlFilterValues
            If ur.Columns(c).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).CountLarge > 1 Then
                For Each cel In ur.Columns(c).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                    If Not IsError(cel.Value2) Then
                        If Len(cel.Value2) > 0 Then
                            cVal = cel.Value2:  pos = 1
                            Do While pos > 0
                                pos = InStr(pos, cVal, wrdArr(w), vbTextCompare)
                                wb = Mid(cVal, pos + Len(wrdArr(w)), 1)
                                If pos > 0 And wb Like "[!a-zA-Z0-9]" Then
                                    sz = Len(wrdArr(w))
                                    With cel.Characters(Start:=pos, Length:=sz).Font
                                        .Bold = True
                                        .Color = -4165632
                                        .Size = 11
                                    End With
                                    pos = pos + sz - 1
                                Else
                                    pos = 0
                                End If
                            Loop
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
            End If
            ur.AutoFilter   'clear filters
        Next
    Next
    enableXL True
    Debug.Print "Time: " & Format(Timer - t, "0.000") & " sec"
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub enableXL(Optional ByVal opt As Boolean = True)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = opt
    Application.EnableEvents = opt
    Application.Calculation = IIf(opt, xlCalculationAutomatic, xlCalculationManual)
End Sub
```

---

Your code uses `ReDim Preserve` in the first loop (twice)

- slight impact on performance for one cell, but for thousands it becomes significant
- `ReDim Preserve` **makes a copy** of the initial arr with the new dimension, then deletes the first arr

Also, Selecting and Activating cells should be avoided - most of the times are not needed and slow down execution

---

**Edit**

I measured the performance between the 2 versions

> ```
> Total cells: 3,060; each cell with 15 words, total search terms: 30
>
> Initial code:               Time: 69.797 sec
> My Code:                    Time:  3.969 sec
> Initial code optimized:     Time:  3.438 sec
> ```

---

Initial code optimized:

```
Option Explicit

Const ALL_WORDS = "word1,word2,word3"

Public Sub TestMatches()
    Dim searchTerms As Variant, cel As Range, t As Double

    t = Timer
    enableXL False
    searchTerms = Split(ALL_WORDS, ",")
    For Each cel In Sheet1.UsedRange
        ChangeAllMatches searchTerms, cel
    Next
    enableXL True
    Debug.Print "Time: " & Format(Timer - t, "0.000") & " sec"
End Sub
```

---

```
Public Sub ChangeAllMatches(ByRef terms As Variant, ByRef cel As Range)
    Dim termStart() As Long  'this array holds starting positions of each match
    Dim termLen() As Long    'this array holds lengths of each matching substring
    Dim response As Variant, term As Variant, strt As Variant, pos As Long, i As Long

    If IsError(cel.Value2) Then Exit Sub    'Do not process error
    If Len(cel.Value2) = 0 Then Exit Sub    'Do not process empty cells
    response = cel.Value2
    If Len(response) > 0 Then
        ReDim termStart(1 To Len(response)) As Long 'create arrays large enough
        ReDim termLen(1 To Len(response)) As Long   'to accommodate any matches
        i = 1: Dim wb As String
        'The loop finds the starting position & length of each matched term
        For Each term In terms              'Iterate through each term
            strt = 1
            Do
                pos = InStr(strt, response, term, vbTextCompare) 'Check for match
                wb = Mid(response, pos + Len(term), 1)
                If pos > 0 And wb Like "[!a-zA-Z0-9]" Then
                    strt = pos + 1          'Keep looking for more substrings
                    termStart(i) = pos      'Add match starting pos to array
                    termLen(i) = Len(term)  'Add match len to array termLen()
                    i = i + 1
                Else
                    pos = 0
                End If
            Loop While pos > 0  'Keep searching until we find no more matches
        Next
        ReDim Preserve termStart(1 To i - 1) 'clean up array
        ReDim Preserve termLen(1 To i - 1)   'remove extra items at the end
        For i = 1 To UBound(termStart) 'Modify matches based on termStart()
            If termStart(i) > 0 Then
                With cel.Characters(Start:=termStart(i), Length:=termLen(i)).Font
                    .Bold = True
                    .Color = -4165632
                    .Size = 11
                End With
            End If
        Next i
    End If
End Sub
```